# Authenticate Header

Tags: javascript, windows, authentication, www-authenticate

I have web application that has Windows authentication running successfully until recently. I didn't do any changes to IIS configuration or code modification or user permissions change.

I can log in to the application, but when javascript does redirect it returns to the same page. I checked with fiddler headers. Once I initially logged-in the header has WWW-Authenticate parameter. When the redirection done through JavaScript code either AJAX or setting `windows.lovation.href='MyPage'` it does not pass WWW-Authenticate header value.

So, once I go directly to any page under this application it loads fine and I see WWW-Authenticate parameter, but with JavaScript the WWW-Authenticate parameter missing. Once again no change was done to server.

I assume it may relate to windows auto updates. But it is just wild guess.